# Using laravel with() to fetch relationship when foreign key is of type double

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this model relationship:

```js
public function reject_process()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Process', 'reject_process_id');
    }
```

And I have this query:

```js
RejectSendProcess::with('reject_process')->normal()
            ->where(function ($q) use ($thisProcess) {
                $q->orWhere('process_id', floatval($thisProcess))
                    ->orWhere('process_id', $thisProcess);
            })
            ->get();
```

My processes table has primary keys(id) with values as double eg (0.5, 1.0).
When I use the query above, I get reject_process to be null when the related process has id of 0.5 despite the fact that it contains data meanwhile  if the related process is like 1.0, I get the related data of reject_process.

How can I resolve this issue such that I get the related data of reject_process whether the value of the foreign key is float or integer.

Answer (score 2):

Primary and foreign keys should never be floats. Floats are imprecise by nature, and their representation depend on too many factors.

I can only imagine a database trying to match a float argument (which won't be exact) in a float index (which won't contain exact values) and not getting any result (expectedly).

I know this does not really answer your question, but you are really doing it wrong. Primary keys and foreign keys should be exact values (integers, strings, binary ids).